# Unable to get a simple jQuery.Ajax call to work

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm pretty new to the web-dev world, and I'm having a bear of a time getting a simple jQuery.ajax call to work.  Here is the call:

```
var url = "http://client.the_url.com/get_account_data.php";  

$.ajax({
  url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(resultsData){
        resultsDataString = JSON.stringify(resultsData, null, 4);
        alert("We're finally making the call.");
      },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error){
          alert("Error");
      } 
});
```

I can copy and paste the url into a browser and it renders what I would expect:

```
{
    "id":"Level 3.xpusdscah",
    "type":"Level 3",
    "name":"xpusdscah",
    "total":0,
    "in":0,
    "out":0
}
```

Instead, I get the Error alert every time. :/.

The php script I'm hitting starts with the header:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

I was trying to pass params to the php script, but now I'm not even doing that.  I would think this should be a 'no brainer', but if it is, then I have no brain.  I'm trying to figure out how to use wireshark right now, but should I really need to use wireshark to debug a call that is as simple as it gets to a php file?

Can anyone help me?  What I'm really hoping for is a "Well *duh*, you didn't do (insert obvious solution here)!

Thanks in advance,
Fledgling web developer

Comment: Is http://client.the_url.com/get_account_data.php the same domain that the script is running?

Comment: You can put `console.log(error)` in the error function to get some details as to what the error is. Open the console to see the log. Saying something along the lines of "it just throws an error" doesn't really help to get a clear answer.

Comment: In first alert statement you have mentioned that the url is url+data but when you are passing the url you (have not yet appeneded the data part to the url) are using the old one. Is that what you intend to do?

Comment: I wonder if the data is serialized correctly on to the querystring. Try 1) adding '?' in front of the data string, 2) give the data as JSON rather than string, or 3) make the call to the complete url ( url+'?'+data )

Comment: Nathan: I know the URL is fine, because I can call other php scripts in the same domain and they work fine.
pimvdb: console.log(error) doesn't end up putting anything in in the error console at all.
Ajai: I am now hard coding all of the data in the .php script, and it is still failing from my ajax call, but succeeding when hit directly from a browser.
supertopi: see comment to Ajai above.

Comment: please, inspect the Network tab and check if the response is correct. Is a 200 response or is something else?

Comment: @user384817. what @Nathan wanted to say is that both the javascript source and `get_account_data.php` should be from same domain. Please modify error handler like this `error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error){
          console.log(xhr.state());
      } ` and check what it is showing. Like @Nathan said it might be a cross-domain issue  http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/same-origin-policy/

Comment: @Nathan you and Diode had the right answer.  It took me WAY longer than I would care to admit to get JSONP working, but it is.  Thanks a ton for your help.  I can't vote for you though, as you didn't post an official "answer". :/

Comment: I just asked a question, don't worry! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, your callback function isn't helpful.  It just shows the text "Error" every time.  You want to actually display what the error is, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data,
      success: function(resultsData){
        resultsDataString = JSON.stringify(resultsData, null, 4);
        alert("We're finally making the call.");
      },
      error:error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          alert("Error:" + textStatus+ "," + errorThrown);
      } 
});
```

Your parameters for the error callback were named strangely. The documentation says the second param is a text error code, and the errorThrown is the HTTP status code provided by the web server.  See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Next, you'll want to grab a packet sniffer.  This will allow you to inspect the packets going to and from the web server and see the error message that it is throwing.  A good free option is [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 0):

The data you're sending is not json.

```
var data = "login="+localLogin+"&pw="+localPassword+"&forAccount="+forAccount+"&forAccountType="+forAccountType+"&topAccount="+topAccount+"&fromDate="+fromDate+"&toDate="+toDate;
```

Should be something like this:

```
var data = '{"Key1":"' + Value1 + '","Key2":"' + Value2 .... + '""}';
```

And perhaps you should add the type as POST and content type like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ....
```

Comment: I'm now hard coding *all the values* in the php script.  I can call the raw URL (no data) from the command line and it renders the JSON I would expect to be returned.  I try from the ajax, and it fails.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, I use asp.net

Answer (score 0):

try these:

- inspect the Network tab on your console.
- copy and paste the response and parse it in the console command line to verify the JSON is well formed.
- show more verbose error description.

Comment: The net tab in firebug shows my request, but the response is 100% completely empty.  When running the php script through the browser, the JSON returned is well formed.  *sigh*.  I'm starting to get kind of frustrated with this. :/.

Comment: ok, check the request parameters are what you expect, and maybe do a var_dump() server side, maybe you get some clue there. Are you sure you are using POST from JS and $_POST in php? or GET in both sides?